# Access the downloads directory from Intel XDK

Tags: android, directory, intel-xdk

If working with android, I could have simply used `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`
However, I could not find a way to access it using intel XDK. Basically my application works on some type of audio mixing for which I need to pick the already downloaded songs from the phone. The platform is android.

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova File plugin may help, depends on where those files are located and whether or not they are private or public files. See this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: I made use of it, I even followed simple examples of file reading even from the application directory itself but it doesn't seem to work. I have included the file and file transfer plugin as well as specified by http://qnimate.com/working-with-file-system-using-intel-xdk/. Can you please help me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you post a very simple example app that tries to locate an example file on the XDK forum and explain where these audio files are located. There are not enough details here to help you with your issue.